# incomplete output in reading N-Triples (.nt) files in Fuseki and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, fuseki, n-triples

I am loading a `N-triple(.nt)` file in `Fuseki` and then using `SPARQL` query to query the data. The `N-triple` file I am using is - `linkedct-dump-2010-02-10.zip` at [this link](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~oktie/linkedct/).

When I view the same file in `Protege ontology editor` ([link here](http://protege.stanford.edu/)) I see following:

[image]

As can be seen there are `Classes` within `Entities`. I am currently working with `trials` class. When I click on any of the `Instances` of `trials` class I see following:
[image]

So it can be seen that there are `Classes` within the data and each `class` has `instances`. Now when in `Fuseki` I try to get all the classes through following SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?type
WHERE {
  ?s a ?type.
}
```

The output I see is just a list of `urls` something like this:

[image]

How do I get the `Classes` within the data and then get `instances` within a specific class(in my case `trials` class) and then select any `Individual Annotations` (in pic 2 you can see individual annotation for a specific instance in trials class as viewed in protege editor) within a specific instance?

**Update:** Following is a sample data i see when I open the .nt file in wordpad:

```
<http://data.linkedct.org/resource/trials/NCT00000102> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/linkedct/condition> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/condition/3196> .
<http://data.linkedct.org/resource/trials/NCT00000104> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/linkedct/condition> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/condition/7149> .
<http://data.linkedct.org/resource/trials/NCT00000105> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/linkedct/condition> <http://data.linkedct.org/resource/condition/2080> .
```

Comment: 1. Technically, your query returns all RDF resources that are used in triples with the predicate `rdf:type`. Basically, and via inference, those are classes. 2. If you want to have all instances of a given class, you have to reflect this in your query, i.e. `?s a lct:trials`. 3. If you want additional information about those instances, again, just do this in your query, i.e. add another triple pattern `?s ?p ?o.` and don't forget to `SELECT` what you need.

Comment: @AKSW I am very new to SPARQL so can you explain through an example query like if i wanted to select `trials` class and instance `Trial NCT00000102` and within this instance an annotation called `condition` then how should my SPARQL query look like?

Comment: How about `?s a ?type . ?type a owl:Class` ?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor When I execute` SELECT DISTINCT ?type WHERE {
 ?s a ?type . ?type a owl:Class.
}` I get 0 results

Comment: Well, OWL isn't RDF, even though OWL can be serialized as RDF. The same OWL ontology might have multiple RDF serializations.  Since you're using an RDF query language (SPARQL) to query OWL serialized as RDF, you'll probably need to take a look into that particular RDF document. Given that it's 1.6G, it's not really likely that a casual StackOverflow user is going to examine it for you in order to answer a question.  Can you post some of the relevant RDF content from that file?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I apologize but I am unable to understand what you mean(I just started with SPARQL today). Can you explain it through an example. For example if i want to get class 'trials' and then instance in that class 'Trial NCT00000102' and say a annotation in that called 'condition' then how can I do that?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have posted the link to the file I am using in my post above.

Comment: @user2966197 Yes, I know you did. That's the only way that I knew (as I mentioned) that it's a 1.6G file.  That's bigger than most people are going to look at just to answer a StackOverflow question.  Since you already have the file, could you post a snippet that you think contains triples that should be appearing for your query?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have added a sample data (in my post above) i see when I open the .nt file in wordpad.

Comment: That is not helpful. Indeed that's how N-Triples look like. I guess Joshua wanted to see the schema triples. I can tell you that there is no proper triple `<s> rdf:type owl:Class` that's why Joshua's query doesn't work here. So you can only use your initial query to get all classes.

Comment: Regarding your question, I already gave you the answer. You can get all instance of a given class with `?s rdf:type <CLASS_URI> .` . And if you have a given instance `s`, you can get the (outgoing) data by using it as subject of a triple pattern, i.e. `<s> ?p ?o .`, and if you want to have just a particular property `p`, indeed replace the `?p` by the URI, i.e. `<s> <p> ?o .` Hope this helps.

Comment: Anyways, you should start with an RDF and SPARQL tutorial. That's how you can learn to write those rather simple queries. Anything else doesn't make sense because otherwise, you'll come back here for any other query that you need.

Comment: [SPARQL Endpoint](http://yasgui.org/#query=PREFIX+rdf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Ftype%0AWHERE+%7B%0A++%3Fs+a+%3Ftype.%0A%7D&contentTypeConstruct=text%2Fturtle&contentTypeSelect=application%2Fsparql-results%2Bjson&endpoint=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.linkedct.org%2Fsparql&requestMethod=POST&tabTitle=Query+1&headers=%7B%7D&outputFormat=table)

Comment: Also, http://static.linkedct.org/snorql/